# RethinkDB Java-дравер возвращает double как Long

Tags: java, rethinkdb

Мы сохраняем данные в клевой БД `RethinkDB`. Проблема возникла с извлечением числовых значений типа Double. Числовые поля могут иметь значения как с дробной частью, так и без нее (пример: 17, 17.0, 17.7). Внутренний формат представления чисел в RethinkDB - 64-битный double. Однако java-драйвер извлекает числа без дробной части как `Long`, а число с дробной частью как `Double`. При этом в классах предметной области жестко прописаны типа полей double. Когда драйвер возвращает Long вместо Double, возникает исключение `ClassCastException`. Как решить эту проблему? Для инициализации каждого поля модели использовать `instanceof` или написать функцию конвертации?

Можно придумать что-то лучше такого костыля?

```
private double convert(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Long) {
            return ((Long) value).doubleValue();
        }
        else return (double) value;
    }
```

Код извлечения значения:

```
public Optional<Invoice> find(String uid) {
    Cursor cursor = r.db("test").table("invoice")
            .getAll(uid).optArg("index", "uid")
            .run(connection);
    if (!cursor.hasNext())
        return Optional.empty();

    HashMap document = (HashMap) cursor.next();

    Invoice result = new Invoice();

    result.setSenderDateTime((String) document.get("senderDateTime"));
    result.setCreateDateTime((OffsetDateTime) document.get("createDateTime"));
    result.setUpdateDateTime((OffsetDateTime) document.get("updateDateTime"));
    result.setUid((String) document.get("uid"));
    result.setDate((String) document.get("date"));
    result.setNumber((Double) document.get("number"));
    result.setMarked((Boolean) document.get("marked"));
    result.setPosted((Boolean) document.get("posted"));
    result.setSenderCityUID((String) document.get("senderCityUID"));


    return Optional.of(result);
}
```

Не нашел аналог JPA/JdbcTemplate для RethinkDB

Comment: Покажите код/запрос извлечения значения - без этого кода трудно что-то посоветовать

P.S. Не знаю, но кто-то постоянно минусует вопросы Java

Comment: @Barmaley, пусть минусуют, раз есть свободное время. Быть может, это кто-то безработный/уволенный/сокращенный

Comment: это похоже на особенность json-simple, который там внутри используется. Он вообще-то для чисел обещает возвращать `java.lang.Number`, поэтому что-то типа `((Number)document.get("number")).doubleValue()` даже и не костыль. Или можете попробовать в `run` передать класс, там, судя по исходникам, будет работать Jackson, который даже можно поконфигурять